# How to manage button state in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

is there a way i can identify one button from others when they seem to represent the same logic.

So i download files from coredata and can play them on "play" button click, but the problem is i am unable to "stop" the already  playing music when i click on another "play" button.

How can i stop this and make sure when one button click implements the logic at a time others toggle to a same opposite state , the button is inside a List which has a ForEach View, kindly guide , thanks..

```
@State var playButton = false -> this outside body
Button(action: {
        playButton.toggle()
     do {
       if playButton {
         self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: songCellVM.song.songMp3!)
         self.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
         self.audioPlayer?.play()       
       }
       else {
         self.audioPlayer?.stop() 
       }
     } catch let error {
         print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
   }
      }){   Image(systemName: playButton ? "playpause" : "play")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: 
        .padding()
      }
```

//-------- The View File which not only changes the play and pause button correctly but also creates a common audioPlayer that can be used to make sure only one song is playing at a time. Also i use the approach as suggest by @adrien to create a binding by making an instance in ViewModel and publishing it and then using a Binding in the View. This makes sure that the View uses the unique instance defined in ViewModel when it is accessed in Cells that get their source of truth from it.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import AVFoundation

struct ArtistViewMain: View {
    
    
    
    @ObservedObject var songsListVM = SongListVM()
    @ObservedObject var repo = SongRepository()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(songsListVM.songCellVMs) {
                        songCellVM in
                        SongCell(songCellVM: songCellVM, selectedSong: $songsListVM.selectedSong, audioPlayer: $songsListVM.audioPlayer)
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Artists")
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}

struct SongCell: View {
    @ObservedObject var songCellVM: SongCellVM
    @State var playButton: Bool = false
  //  @State var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
    @Binding var selectedSong: Song?
    @Binding var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    var isSelected: Bool { songCellVM.song.id == selectedSong?.id }
    var onCommit: () -> () = {  }
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            
            Text(songCellVM.song.artistname)
            Spacer()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: songCellVM.song.artistImage ?? Data()) ?? UIImage())
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70, alignment: .center)
                .scaledToFit()
                .cornerRadius(20)
            
            //----
            
            Button(action: {
                self.audioPlayer?.stop()
              
                if isSelected  {
                    
                    selectedSong = nil
                   
                    
                } else {
                  
                    selectedSong = songCellVM.song
                    
                    do {
                        self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: songCellVM.song.songMp3!)
                        self.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                        self.audioPlayer?.play()
                       
                        
                        
                        
                    } catch let error {
                        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
            }){     Image(systemName: isSelected ? "playpause" : "play")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .padding()
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            
            //            .onAppear {
            //                if playButton == true {
            //                    playButton.toggle()
            //                }
            //            }
                        .onDisappear{
                           // self.playButton.toggle()
                            self.audioPlayer?.stop()
                        }
            
            
            //--------
            
            //-----
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reused your project by simplifying it for the example :

## Model :

```
struct Song: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    // let songMP3: Data
    // let image: Image
}
```

## ViewModels :

In your `SongListViewModel` you need to store the song that was selected. I create a `@Published` variable (`selectedSong`), that is a `Song?` (optional : so if no song is selected, it is `nil`).

```
class SongCellViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var song: Song
    init(song: Song) {
        self.song = song
    }
}

class SongListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var songVMlist: [SongCellViewModel] = [
        .init(song: .init(name: "Bala")),
        .init(song: .init(name: "Folk Lore")),
    ]
    @Published var selectedSong: Song?
}
```

## Views :

I create a Binding on `selectedSong` . This is the point that interests us.
All `SongCell` can modify this variable.
As this variable is stored in the parent view (or rather in its ViewModel), if it's modified, it impacts all `SongCell`.
The icon depends on the value of `selectedSong`.

Note: rather than a Binding, we could manage the observation of changes (with Combine) in the `SongListViewModel`. But I kept it simple.

```
struct SongList: View {
    @StateObject var listVM = SongListViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List(listVM.songVMlist) { cellVM in
            SongCell(songCellVM: cellVM, selectedSong: $listVM.selectedSong)
        }
    }
}

struct SongCell: View {
    @ObservedObject var songCellVM: SongCellViewModel
    @Binding var selectedSong: Song?
    var isSelected: Bool { songCellVM.song.id == selectedSong?.id }
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(songCellVM.song.name)
            Spacer()
            Button {
                if isSelected {
                    selectedSong = nil
                } else {
                    selectedSong = songCellVM.song
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: isSelected ? "playpause" : "play")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .padding()
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

## EDIT

new question :

> now though the images of play and pause change, i still am unable to
> stop multiple songs from playing at same time, my new code is added in
> end of question

new answer :

In your project each `SongCell` has its own `AVPlayer`. They all have to share the same player. We can use this approach :

1. Create a class that will wrap your `AVPlayer`
   (I did that quickly, you'll have to replace the code in the `launchPlayer` function)

```
class AVPlayerManager {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    func launchPlayer(with title: String) {
        guard let dataAsset = NSDataAsset(name: title) else { return }
        audioPlayer = try? perform(AVAudioPlayer(data: dataAsset.data, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue),
                                 orThrow: AudioLoaderError.loadPlayer)
        audioPlayer?.play()
    }
    func pausePlayer() {
        audioPlayer?.pause()
    }
}
```

2. We instantiate this new class in the `SongListViewModel`. And we give its reference to the `SongCellViewModel`s :

```
class SongCellViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var song: Song
    var player: AVPlayerManager?
    init(song: Song, player: AVPlayerManager? = nil) {
        self.song = song
    }
}

class SongListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var songVMlist: [SongCellViewModel]
    @Published var selectedSong: Song?
    var player: AVPlayerManager = AVPlayerManager()
    init() {
        songVMlist = [
            .init(song: .init(name: "Bala")),
            .init(song: .init(name: "Folk Lore")),
        ]
        _ = songVMlist.map {$0.player = player}
    }
}
```

3. We can now use it in the `CellView`s :

```
songCellVM.player?.pausePlayer()
```

and

```
songCellVM.player?.launchPlayer(with: "name_of_your_mp3_in_the_assets")
```

Comment: thanks for this , however now though the images of play and pause change, i still am unable to stop multiple songs from playing at same time, my new code is added in end of question, can you kindly suggest a way around this ?

Comment: did you try to move `self.audioPlayer?.stop()` just before `if isSelected` ?

Comment: yes i have been trying to do every possible combination , but the songs just keep playing and overlapping each other ...i am posting the whole code in my question , thanks again

Comment: @multiverse : If you edit your question please specify it in the question and explain why.
Otherwise it will no longer be understandable in the future.
For your new problem: each `SongCell` has its own `AVPlayer`. They all have to share the same player. So place your (unique) player in the `SongList`, and give its reference to the `SongCell`s.

Comment: @multiverse : If you want to do this quickly, you can do a Binding exactly like we did with `selectedSong` but with `audioPlayer`

Comment: @multiverse : I edited my answer with an other approach.

Comment: thank you , i used your instructions to do the binding like you have done with selectedSong, this problem has made me understand combine a bit better , i was a bit confused with all the moving parts. I updated my question also.